# Can't Export APK from Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, admob, apk

I was wondering I can't export apk file from Eclipse ADT after I success migrate new Mobile Ads SDK replacing the old `AdmobSDK 6.4.1`.

After I migrate to the Google play service - Mobile Ads SDK, I couldn't export apk and it's appear error like below:

```
[2014-02-11 15:20:25 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
[2014-02-11 15:20:25 - AnimalMemoryGame] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

Anybody here can explain me on this matter?

Comment: I think you you added some thing two times.like jar ,admob SDK etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with your imports probably your project are using the same two libraries (older and new) and do not know with one should be used.

Check your Libs files, lib-project and  references